# Bound of a complex integral with itself

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, absolute-value, complex-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I already asked a [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702375/bounding-the-absolute-value-of-a-complex-integral) [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361997/bounding-the-absolute-value-of-a-complex-integral) on this topic, but after a small discussion and a [new finding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703933/bound-on-a-complex-integral-using-polar-form?noredirect=1#comment7615160_3703933), I noted that I did must boil down the problem such that the solution space shrinks so to say, to maybe have a concrete answer. I am still not a complex analysis or measure theory expert, so I hope that this simplification helps to solve the problem...

Suppose I have two rational, complex functions, mapping from the real numbers to the complex plane
$$f(ix) = \frac{p(ix)}{q(ix)} \qquad \text{and}\qquad g(ix) = \frac{r(ix)}{s(ix)}$$
Furthermore, the polynomials $q$ and $s$ do not have zeros on the imaginary axis (or if it simplifies the problem, the right half complex plane), and I know that $|g(ix)|\le 1 \ \forall x$. I can also assume that $\mathrm{deg}(p)\le\mathrm{deg}(q)$ and $\mathrm{deg}(r)\le\mathrm{deg}(s)$, and the polynomials do not have common factors.

Is it then true to state that 
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right|\le \left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)\mathrm{d}x\right| \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\quad?$$

I have the idea that this must be true, due to the fact that the functions are holomorphic on the imaginary axis *(correct me if I'm wrong)*, and the functions are proper. But again, I cannot prove this... I tried to find a counter example, but up to now this inequality holds in simulation :P

---

If this is not enough information to solve the problem, I may have another relaxation that can solve the problem... In my application it is also possible to formulate an additional function $h(ix)$ for which we know that $|h(ix)|=1 \ \forall x$ and $\angle h(ix)=\angle g(ix) \ \forall x$. Then the inequality I would like to hold becomes
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right|\le \left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)h(ix)\mathrm{d}x\right| \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

When I use the above, I think it is true to conclude that 
$$\angle\left\{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right\} = \angle\left\{ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)h(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right\},$$
since $\angle h(ix)=\angle g(ix)$. Suppose this angle is $\theta$, then if we write $g$ and $h$ as a complex exponential, we have
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right| = e^{-i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x = e^{-i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)G(x)e^{i\tilde{g}(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)h(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right| = e^{-i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)h(ix)\mathrm{d}x = e^{-i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)\cdot1\cdot e^{i\tilde{h}(x)}\mathrm{d}x,$$
with $\tilde{g},\tilde{h}$ functions that describe the phase of $g$ and $h$, respectively, and $G(x)$ describing the modulus of $g$. Since I assumed that $\angle h(ix)=\angle g(ix)$, we have 
$$\mathbb{R}\ni\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)g(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right| = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \underbrace{G(x)}_{\in[0,1]}f(ix)e^{i(\tilde{h}(x)-\theta)}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\mathbb{R}\ni\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)h(ix)\mathrm{d}x \right| = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix) e^{i(\tilde{h}(x)-\theta)}\mathrm{d}x,$$
Then you would say that the lower term is an upperbound for the upperterm?! Or what does not hold in this analysis?

Comment: If $q$ doesn't have zeroes in the right half-plane and $\deg q \ge \deg p +2$ the RHS integral is zero as the function is analytic on the right half-plane, its integral on a contour that goes from $[-iR, iR]$ and then back on the semicircle of radius $R$ is zero by Cauchy and the semicircle integral is $O(1/R) \to 0, R \to \infty$; same result is true for the LHS integral if $s$ also doesn;t have zeroes in the right half plane and the degrees satisfy same relation for $pr/qs$ - so the problem is kind of trivial in this case

Comment: @Conrad Thank for the reactions on this and previous questions! Would the problem also be solvable if we only assume q and s do not have zeros on the imaginary axis? And is the derivation in the edit I did possible?

Comment: I do not think the result is true in general since playing with residues one can easily get an example where RHS is zero even with zeroes in the right half-plane, but LHS is not as multiplying by even a small $g$ will mess up the residues - if the degrees $p,q$ differ only by $1$ (they cannot be same if the integral converges) then the integral won't converge absolutely though of course, it may converge as a symmetric limit but the same residue theorems apply except that now the semicircle integral will have a non-zero limit

Comment: the last paragraph is not true - even if the integrals are real and $G$ is positive there is no reason for any general inequality (think in terms of sums that alternate and what happens if you multiply the terms by some positive numbers - if you multiply say the positive terms by much more than the negative terms, even if the multipliers are less than $1$ the effect of making the negative-sum much smaller in absolute value will more than compensate for the decrease in the positive sum due to the multipliers, so the overall sum will be bigger than the original;

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for all your comments, you helped me out a lot!

Comment: happy to be of help - this topic (estimates for oscillating sums/integrals) is of great interest and is quite difficult